# Find out ip of server android app is using

Tags: android, ip, apk

So, i am testing my app, it saves data of accounts to a server, and i am wondering if it is possible to get server ip by just having app instaled.
Is there some methods?

Comment: Installed is not enough. An app should run in order to do something.

Comment: Strange question. If you know the server by name there are plenty of methods to determine ip. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  You can get the IP just by checking the router and seeing where requests were made to, you don't even need to run the app-  just someone on the network needs to.  IP addresses aren't secret.